# how can i convert chr into something else and divide it into 4 unit?

Tags: r

for example, below is a chr(or factor), how can I divide this into 4 unit in r.

[{'id': 4379, 'name': 'time travel'}, {'id': 9663, 'name': 'sequel'}, {'id': 11830, 'name': 'hot tub'}, {'id': 179431, 'name': 'duringcreditsstinger'}]

Comment: Can you be more precise in your question, or add an expected output?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
> unlist(strsplit(gsub("}, {", "}], [{", s, fixed = TRUE), "(?<=]),\\s+", perl = TRUE))
[1] "[{'id': 4379, 'name': 'time travel'}]"
[2] "[{'id': 9663, 'name': 'sequel'}]"
[3] "[{'id': 11830, 'name': 'hot tub'}]"
[4] "[{'id': 179431, 'name': 'duringcreditsstinger'}]"
```

**Data**

```
s <- "[{'id': 4379, 'name': 'time travel'}, {'id': 9663, 'name': 'sequel'}, {'id': 11830, 'name': 'hot tub'}, {'id': 179431, 'name': 'duringcreditsstinger'}]"
```